# Print all en-queued scripts/styles

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add async attribute in my rander js and css script .
for these I amusing this script for print en-queued script .but this code is 
only print some admin js not more.I am using this code from  git hub and other stack overflow solution , but not able to print all script .

```
<?php 
/*  
* Getting script tags
* Thanks http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54064/how-do-i-get-the-handle-for-all-enqueued-scripts
*/
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wsds_detect_enqueued_scripts' );
function wsds_detect_enqueued_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) :
        echo $handle . ' | ';
    endforeach;
}
?>
```

Comment: You'll see all admin/backend scripts if you're in backend / admin panel. Please check your front end to see all the front end scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna see all the registered or enqueued scripts then try the following code. `$wp_scripts->queue` will only show those scripts that are going to be printed or added to site.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wsds_detect_enqueued_scripts' );
function wsds_detect_enqueued_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    foreach( $wp_scripts->registered as $script ) {
        echo $script->handle . ' | ';
    }
}
```

Comment: obiPlabon@can you let me know how can i stop render css without plugin.

Comment: You mean you want to remove render css or want to dequeue that? If yes then please check https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script or you can use https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script

Comment: obiPlabon@I want asynch  or defer tag in css